# Getting Timeout error while connecting MongoDB Atlas with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to connect to my database on MongoDB Atlas using mongoose. But every time it's giving me the following error:

```
(node:2327) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: queryTxt ETIMEOUT cluster0-abjwg.gcp.mongodb.net
at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:206:19)
(node:2327) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:2327) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I have tried whitelisting the IP. Also, the same code is working fine on another machine but not on my machine.

The code is:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

// Connecting to MongoDB
const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri, {useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log('Connection established');
})

app.use(express.json());

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Here we go on port: ${port}`);
});
```

It is supposed to give output:

```
Here we go on port: 5000
Connection established
```

But I'm getting the only the first output and the error.

Answer (score 1):

DNS resolution for TXT records appears to be broken on your machine. You can use the legacy URI (the one without `srv`) to connect instead.

Comment: Please elaborate. Or suggest me some tutorial or blog to do the same.

Comment: I don't know why it's broken but it seems like a common issue. Maybe something to do with systemd.

Comment: I changed my DNS to Google's DNS. Now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

My Internet Service Provider was blocking the connection. I changed my DNS to Google's Public DNS and the error was no more. I followed the link below to change my DNS.
https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using