# Connection to MongoDB atlas using Node.js driver fails

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-atlas

```
  at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:203:19) {
  errno: 'ETIMEOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEOUT',
  syscall: 'queryTxt',
  hostname: 'scheduly.1eln0.mongodb.net'
}
```

I’m facing the above connection Error while connecting with MongoDB Atlas. I’ve double-checked my username and password. I’ve whitelisted all the IP’s. I’m stuck in the middle of a project and cannot connect to the DB itself.
my connection strings are:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const mongodb = require("mongodb");
const uri = "mongodb+srv://ghulamghousdev:***********@scheduly.1eln0.mongodb.net/scheduly?retryWrites=true&w=majority

mongoose
  .connect(uri, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected");
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

The name of the Database on MongoDB atlas is scheduly.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62758525/getting-timeout-error-while-connecting-mongodb-atlas-with-mongoose/62759942#62759942.

Comment: Can you tell me how to change DNS to Google's DNS?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?t=palemoon&q=change+dns+to+google+dns&ia=web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to add the ip of your VPS, host to the IP Whitelist of Network access?
You can see more details for that setting from here https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/

Comment: Yes, I did. I tried both the ways i.e. by adding public IP address and also by adding my personal IP address. But neither worked for me. I followed the documentation but same error still persists.