# Unable to connect to mongodb free atlas using Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pip, mongodb-query, pymongo

My code for establishing the db connection for mongodb atlas is:-

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pprint import pprint

def db_connect():
    client = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://user1:<pwd>@<Cluster name>/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
    db = client.admin
    serverStatusResult = db.command("serverStatus")
    return pprint(serverStatusResult)
```

I am calling the db_connect() function from a django API call using

```
class Answer(APIView):
    def get(self, request, question):
        try:
            print(db_connect())
            # model=Users.objects.get(id=employee_id)
        except Question.DoesNotExist:
            return Response('Answer not found', status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        # serializers=UsersSerializer(model)
        return Response(db_connect())
```

***Note:-**Ive added my password and cluster name.Jst for posting the question I removed it
But I am getting the error

```
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/api/question/what%20are%20the%20year%20wise%20sales
Django Version: 3.0.7
Exception Type: ConfigurationError
Exception Value:    
None of DNS query names exist: _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.vjcqw.mongodb.net., _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.vjcqw.mongodb.net.epam.com., _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.vjcqw.mongodb.net.minsk.epam.com., _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.vjcqw.mongodb.net.moscow.epam.com., _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.vjcqw.mongodb.net.princeton.epam.com., _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.vjcqw.mongodb.net.petersburg.epam.com., _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.vjcqw.mongodb.net.samara.epam.com., _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.vjcqw.mongodb.net.saratov.epam.com., _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.vjcqw.mongodb.net.budapest.epam.com., _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.vjcqw.mongodb.net.kyiv.epam.com., _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.vjcqw.mongodb.net.accelerite.com.
Exception Location: F:\heroku\lib\site-packages\pymongo\srv_resolver.py in _resolve_uri, line 79
Python Executable:  F:\heroku\Scripts\python.exe
```

What could be the reason for this error

Comment: Specify your password and cluster name in: ```client = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://user1:<pwd>@<Cluster name>/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority")```

Comment: Yes ,I added it but still not getting,just for posting the question I removed it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62758525/getting-timeout-error-while-connecting-mongodb-atlas-with-mongoose/62759942#62759942